# How to extract Date and from a String in java

Tags: java

I have a string of day, date and time that is `String myDateString = "Fri, 07 Jun 2013 09:30:00";`.For date  `January 2, 2010` we use `new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(mystring);`. What can I use instead of `MMMM d, yyyy` in my situation

Now How can I extract day, year, month, day of the month, hours, minutes and seconds from the string in the following pattern.

`day: Fri`,
`Year: 2013`,
`Month: Jun`,
`day of the Month: 07`,
`Hour: 09`,
`Minutes: 30` and
`Seconds: 00`,

Please help me in this respect I would be very thankful to you for this act of kindness. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ~Think the reason for all the downvotes is that this is a dupe of  [Parsing Java String to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408116/parsing-java-string-to-date?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) from standard library. Something like following:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(myDateString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Reference these formats [Java Date Format Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

[image: Formats for datetime]

try this code:

```
Date tempDate = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("Fri, 09 12 2013 09:30:00");
System.out.println("Current Date " +tempDate);
```

Comment: Can you complete your post by adding the solution of the problem: a call to SimpleDateFormat.parse()?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object to extract the date and put it into a `util.Date` object. From there extract the individual attributes you need.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
String myDateString = "Fri, 07 Jun 2013 09:30:00";
Date myDate = null;
// attempting to parse the String with a known format
try {
    myDate =  
        new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
            .parse(myDateString);           
}       
// something went wrong...
catch (Throwable t) {
    // just for debug
    t.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    if (myDate != null) {
    // just for checking...
    System.out.println(myDate);
    // TODO manipulate with calendar        
    }
}
```

This will work if you are certain that the format you receive will always be consistent. 
You can then split your date into different values by initializing a Calendar object, then retrieving its various fields.

For instance:

```
// once you're sure the date has been parsed
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(myTimeZone, myLocale);
calendar.setTime(myDate);
// prints the year only 
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Comment: You're supposed to use the `myDate` within the `try` block. There's no reason to have a `finally` block for this...

Comment: Thank you, I agree. I wrote the snippet a bit too quickly I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to split the string

```
String[] parts = "Fri, 07 Jun 2013 09:30:00".split("[ :,]+");
```

this will produce an array

```
[Fri, 07, Jun, 2013, 09, 30, 00]
```

then use its elements

```
String dayOfWeek = parts[0];
...
```